# Why is it not recommended to keep the shared libraries in the Executable location

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm Fairly new to Linux , And Software Development I was suggested that the shared library should be placed separately from the executable location in Linux , But in Windows I could see  all the Files including the dll's and the exe are available in the same folder .What kind of problem's it might cause in linux if the exe and the shared library are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executable and library in same folder you can't say library is shared, right? And you'll probably have dozens of same libraries in system - what a waste of space. In Windows there's no organized way of storing libraries in system line /usr/bin or /lib/bin. It's not ok to put them in system32, and there's no other directories in PATH - no choice to make.

Comment: hi overloop , will the shared libraries kept in the executable location cause problems ?

Comment: No, exept it's not a linux-way. Some application that demand very specific environment distributed with that environment, like sage, for example http://www.sagemath.org/index.html